# Strategy to count sum from child records by plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm

Consider a custom entity with child records like opportunity, quote, order or invoice. I’d like to calculate the sum of the child records and save it to the parent record. I’ve tried several approaches but each one has some drawback.

1. Processing only the change to the sum on Pre-Operation. Addition
   for Create, subtraction and addition for Update, and subtraction for
   Delete.

*Problems: Can’t force a recalculation (recalculation of
already existing elements; recover after mistakes). It works only
for sums, but not for other aggregations.*

2. A change of a child fires the complete recalculation of the parent
   (Post-Operation).

*Problems: Can’t get the parent, when a child is
    already deleted (and Pre-Operation is too early to recalculate). The
    complete recalculation is supposed to be slower.*

3. The asynchronous variation of the previous one. Sync Pre-Operation
   of a child triggers asynchronous recalculation of the parent.

*Problems: This might work great, but it really confuses users (they
    don’t see the change; they can’t print a report immediately).*

Is there some better way to do it? Maybe combine 1 and 2? Am I missing something? This problem seems to be very easy in general. But considering SDK/limitations of MSCRM, it is getting complicated.

Comment: https://crmgenericrollup.codeplex.com/

Comment: Too broad to answer, there are a ton of possible answers which would need to include some sort of analysis of the problem.

Comment: Another option - in CRM 2015 you can use rollup fields...

Comment: The rollup fields work great in 2015, but they are still asynchronous – recalculated once per hour. At least, the recalculation can be easily forced. It might be a reasonable compromise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[crmgenericrollup.codeplex.com](http://crmgenericrollup.codeplex.com) that offers this functionality as prepared solution (suggested by Guido Preite) solve this by **calculating the field in plugin for the child element and excluding the record being deleted** (on PRE DELETE)

```csh
//third parameter for deleting
protected void CalculateAggregate(LocalPluginContext localContext, 
                                  RollupSettings rollupSetting, 
                                  bool ignoreThisRecord = false)
{
    if (ignoreThisRecord)
    {
        fetchXml = string.Format(@"
          <fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
             <entity name='{0}'> 
               <attribute name='{1}' alias='A' aggregate='{2}'/> 
               <filter>
                 <condition attribute='{3}' operator='eq' value='{4}' />
                 <condition attribute='{5}' operator='neq' value='{6}' />
               </filter>
              </entity> 
          </fetch>", 
          rollupSetting.ChildEntity, rollupSetting.ChildEntityAttribute, 
          rollupSetting.RollupType.ToString(), rollupSetting.LookupAttribute, 
          rollupSetting.ParentEntity.Id.ToString(), rollupSetting.ChildEntityIdColumn, 
          localContext.PluginExecutionContext.PrimaryEntityId.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
      // ...
    }
 }
```

It works great. I only miss the chance to force the recalculation. If needed, I realized I can inform the parent record about the excluded record differently.

My solution uses a field `new_recalculate` (datetime) on the parent record. Its change (by plugin, by workflow, manually) fires recalculation and it also holds the time of the last recalculation.

Now, there are two possibilities to proceed. 1) To mark child entity before delete by setting field `new_beingdelete = true` and exclude childs with this flag from calculation. 2) To save id of the child to the lookup field on the parent before deleting the child and exclude it in the roll-up. Second choice seems more complicated, but it is more suitable if a change of the parent record on a child is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding aggregations i would provide you with a few options (in order of complexity):

1. In case you do not need a the functionality, and you just need to show the aggregation results in a report, make the aggregation count through the report. Should be much simpler and a time saver.
2. Add a button on Homepage grid, or the Form of a record, which when clicked will update the aggregations for a certain record. You can do it through a plugin or a javascript calculation. This would, of course, require a user action.
3. The option you are using with the following logic:

   - PLUGIN ON CREATE(post create), to check if parent field is set, and if it is, count the total number of child records for this entity and update the parent field with the count. So do NOT add one, but make the count on all of the records. This way you will no make a bad count if the plugin failed before.
   - PLUGIN ON UPDATE(post update with images pre and post), of the parent field, update both the old and the new value of the parent record with the total count
   - PLUGIN ON DELETE(pre operation on delete of the record), which will update the total number of records in the parent record, make a count of all records without this last one.

     Note: should be checked if the associate and disassociate message should be used as well, but i think the plugin on update will handle this.
4. Make a periodic workflow which will execute a plugin on a custom "aggregator" entity, on a certain period of time defined in the workflow. This plugin will have to query all the parent records, and calculate aggregations for each one. You can use this option in the combination with the previous one, and maybe running it once a day, for correct updating of data.

Comment: The problem is to see the aggregation in the field, immediately and without any other action; e.g. like the revenue in Opportunity. Not later, not in report, not after another click. I’ve seen also solution based on Roll-Up Queries. Regarding 3) ON DELETE: How can I get the parent record on POST DELETE?

Comment: Just realized it's a mistake about the on delete, you should register the plugin on Delete on pre-operation and query the record to retrieve the value of the field. I've edited the answer for this. 

Something like Entity entityImage = service.retrieve(t_Entity.LogicalName, t_Entity.Id, new ColumnSet(new string[] { "parentcustomerid" }));